# How do I select the minimum date and total_sales from this table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, amazon-redshift

I need to select the minimum date and amount from this table, how do I do it?

```
Table:

|user_id |date       |amount         |
---------+-----------+----------------
|1       |2014-08-19 | 1000
|2       |2014-12-04 | 20000
|2       |2014-01-09 | 21000
|1       |2015-02-26 | 6000
|2       |2015-03-15 | 27000
|1       |2015-10-26 | 8000
```

Expected result:

```
|user_id |date       |amount         |
---------+-----------+----------------
|1       |2014-08-19 | 1000
|2       |2014-12-04 | 20000
```

Comment: Are you requesting help for Amazon Redshift, or for PostgreSQL? The answer is different depending upon the database.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Redshift

Comment: You mention that you want *"the minimum date and amount"*, but `user_id` 2 has a minimum date of `2014-01-09`, yet the expected result is showing `2014-12-04`. Are you really saying that you wish to display one row per user, where the amount is the smallest amount for that user, and the date is from the same row as that minimum amount?

Comment: Also, your question Title says *"How do I select the minimum date and total_sales from this table?"*, which is also different to what is asked within the question.

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, use `distinct on`

```
select distinct on (user_id) t.*
from t
order by user_id, date asc;
```

`distinct on` returns one row for each combination of keys in the parenthesized list.  The keys in the list need to be the first keys for the order by.  The query returns the first row encountered.  In this case, the one with the minimum `date` (based on `date` asc).

If RedShift doesn't support `distinct on`, then just use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date) as seqnum
      from t 
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon - would you know how to do it in Amazon Redshift as well?